# How to delete iOS on-device crash reports without syncing?

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

We have a number of developer devices and over the course of development they have filled up with so many crash reports that the device refuses to store any more. I want to delete the reports, but according to Apple the only way to do that is by syncing with iTunes. However, I don't want to sync gigs and gigs of useless data from multiple development devices just to clear out the crash logs.

I'd always figured that deleting them from the organizer in Xcode would do the trick, but that's not the case: Even though the organizer shows only 1 crash report under device logs, Settings -> General -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostics & Usage Data shows a GIANT list of reports that don't show up in Xcode.

Is there a way to clear out all crash reports without having to fill up my hard drive by syncing each and every development device?

Answer (score 0):

For our development devices, we just do an Erase all Content and Settings which restores the device to brand new.

This way we can be sure that the device is not showing behavior that might be related to running code still under development.